# error while adding image using R.drawable.myimagename

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

this is the error, "myimagename" couldnot be resolved or is not a field.

ps:

myimagename.jpg is present in the drawable folder.

Comment: Post your code and a stack trace.

Comment: i am unable post whole code, it is displaying some formating error.

Comment: image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img1);

//the img1 is not recognised

thanxx for yur reply

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clean your project.

In Eclipse, click Project in the top menu, click Clean..., choose your project and hit "OK".